# jQuery clearing the value for hidden fields prior to the submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that hides/shows fields based on a dropdown value.  If a user says they are bringing 5 guests by selecting 5 from the dropdown, they are given 5 name fields for the names of their guests.  I would like to clear the name fields of hidden inputs prior to submission to ensure that the user doesn't choose 5 guests, fill them in, then click 2 from the dropdown and submit the form thinking they are choosing 2 guests(when in reality they are submitting data for 5 guests).  I know I can set the value by using

```
$('input:hidden').val('')
```

but I can't seem to make this happen before submission.  I also tried putting the above in the event handler for the dropdown but that won't work for some reason:

```
guestNumberInput.change(function () {
    var inputNumber = $(this).val();
    $(".guest-options").children().slice(0, inputNumber).show(guestTransition);
    $(".guest-options").children().slice(inputNumber).hide(guestTransition);
    $('input:hidden').val('');

  });
```

Im sorry if this is a noob question but I am just starting with jQuery.

Comment: You can put it into your form submit handler: `$('#yourFormID').submit(function() { $('input:hidden').val(''); });`

Comment: How are you hiding and showing the fields?

Comment: I tried this:     $('.rsvp-submit').submit(function(){
            $('input:hidden').val('');
          });                                                                 but it doesn't work.  Can I not call the .submit on a class?

Comment: OH nevermind I am an idiot.  I guess since Im using rails I didn't realize the form had an id untill I checked the source.